# How to allow selected points and confidence intervals to display on graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I have a dataset with species `SP1 and SP2` and abiotic variables `AB1 and AB2`. I want to plot all of them on the graph but with modifications

- Points: Display on SP1 and SP2 but NOT the AB1 and AB2 points on the graph
- Lines: The AB lines should be black, dashed (see code attempt that did not work)
- Confidence intervals: Only the SP lines need to have confidence intervals. The confidence intervals should have alpha = 0.2

  ```
  set.seed(111)
  var <- rep(c("SP1","SP2","AB1","AB2"), times = 5)
  var.val <- rnorm(20,5,1)
  level <- rep(c(100,200,300,400), each = 5)
  df <- data.frame(var, var.val, level)

  ggplot(df, aes(x = level, y = var.val, col = var, group = var)) + 
  geom_point(aes(fill = var),colour="white",pch=21, size=4, stroke = 1, alpha = 0.7, position = pd) + theme_classic() + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", formula = y ~ x ) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("dashed", "dashed","solid", "solid")) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("black","black","red","blue"))
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by passing filtered versions of the data frame to each layer:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = level, y = var.val, col = var, group = var)) + 
geom_point(aes(fill = var), colour="white",pch=21, size=4, stroke = 1,
           alpha = 0.7, data = df[df$var %in% c("SP1", "SP2"),]) +
theme_classic() + 
geom_smooth(data = df[df$var %in% c("SP1", "SP2"),],
            method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, alpha = 0.2) +
geom_smooth(data = df[!df$var %in% c("SP1", "SP2"),],
            method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE, linetype = 2 ) +  
scale_linetype_manual(values = c("dashed", "dashed","solid", "solid")) + 
scale_colour_manual(values = c("black","black","red","blue"))
```

[image]

Though if AB and SP are conceptually two different variables, you might want to consider pivoting to a wider format.